# Are questions about reach, target, and safety schools acceptable?

Tags: discussion

That was the intent of [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167737/what-levels-of-graduate-schools-can-various-combinations-of-gpas-and-gres-get-yo), which was closed (as a "duplicate"). Perhaps I did not make this intent clear enough, and I would welcome any suggestions in that direction. Assuming I succeed in that initial task...

Of course, college admissions, both graduate and undergrad, rely heavily on "soft" factors like the quality of research letters of recommendation. Even so, grades and test scores will help sort candidates into probable*, possible and unlikely candidates for different schools. Or different schools might fall into the category of reach, target, and safety for the same candidate. Would a properly asked question about a "first pass" evaluation be acceptable here?

I can see the question being closed for other reasons, but not as a "duplicate." The gist of the other question was, if you have "low end" credentials, how can you attract enough favor from admissions officers to compensate? My question was the opposite: Assuming that you have high end (or at least moderate) formal credentials how do you evaluate yourself against other high end candidates to estimate whether the schools you are applying to are reach or target schools?

*Here, "probable" would mean relatively probable. If your chances of being accepted to a particular school are about 25%, and that school accepts only 5% of candidates, I would consider you a "probable," even though less than 50-50.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing the general point of the answer marked as duplicate, which is that the admissions process is based on a complex combination of factors that are judged by human beings by their own personal criteria, not a machine or formula. That makes it basically impossible for anyone to judge your chances in any situation unless perhaps your chance is zero.

Ultimately the probability that you are admitted is either zero or one, you find out when you apply.

The duplicate target also says "**particularly** for weak or borderline students" - that is, it's geared a bit towards that group because that's the common question that gets reposted here all the time, but not limited to those who are unsure they will be admitted to any graduate school at all. As you point out, a selective program will choose a mere fraction of applicants, and will reject many strong candidates. So, for that program, really *everyone* is a borderline applicant in some sense.